# undefined method in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, erb

I'm using carrierwave (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnVIRa7Jr6E) to for someone to get and post an image. But, in my show.html.erb file, it says that I have an unidentified method:

```
<%= image_tag @article.image_tag.to_s %>
```

"image_tag" is my undefined method
and in my controller:

```
private
      def article_params
          params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :image_tag)
      end
```

if you need it, I have a painting model (painting.rb):

```
class Painting < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessable :gallary_id, :name, :image
    belongs_to :gallary
    mound_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Comment: this also might help if you need to understand my code: https://github.com/BBaughn1/saving-git

Comment: You have a typo error in your model, it is attr_accessible not attr_accessable (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_accessible/class). I'm not sure why you need those anyway. Another strange thing is your uploader. You mount it on image an you seem to call image_tag are we missing something?

Comment: they way I have it set up is from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnVIRa7Jr6E and doing mostly what he is (only for the picture part). If I take out "@article.image_tag.to_s" and just have "@article," then it will work but won't post the actual picture. don't know if that helps or not

Comment: If you want to take advantage of the Painting class in an Article, you'll need to set a relation (belongs_to/has_one or many depending on what you're doing) then you will be able to call something like @article.painting.image (and use the url function that carrierewave will provide)

Comment: Am I the only one disturbed to see Ryan Bates's screencasts being monetized (almost certainly without permission) by someone who is implicitly feigning association with a (seemingly) popular company and also accepting donations via PayPal?  http://railscasts.com/

Comment: ^^^   I don't really watch his youtube channel, I was trying to figure out what he was doing then seeing if I can put something simular into my work

Comment: I didn't mean to imply any negative reflection on you.  Railscasts was really helpful to me when I was first learning rails so it just really rubbed me the wrong way when I saw that.

Comment: I didn't see the youtube video, but as  ihaztehcodez says Railscasts is a blessing. We should not promote other source for the Ryan's work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use:

```
<%= image_tag @article.image %> or maybe <%= image_tag @article.image.url %>
```

On your code on Github there's something strange. Your Article class do not have an image or an uploader for something. And the painting class is not in a relationship with Article either.

If you want to try something to test carrierwave, I suggest you add a migration for the article let's say a miniature. And then mount the uploader on this field. Then call it in your view.

The carrierwave documentation should be useful:  https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

EDIT

Here is what you can do (simple experiment):

First let's add add a new column for the article.

```
rails g migration addImageToArticle image:string
```

Run the migration

```
rake db:migrate
```

Mount the uploader on the Article class:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    validates :title, presence: true,
                      length: { minimum: 5 }

    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Update your ArticlesController

```
params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :image_tag, :image)
```

Add the field in your form:

```
<%= f.file_field :image %>
```

Then use it in the views (articles/show)

```
<%= image_tag @article.image.url %> or <%= image_tag @article.image_url %> (as the carrierwave doc suggests)
```

Now it should work!

If your new to Rails, I would suggest this video too: http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

Comment: they both give me an error saying that "image" is an undefined method

Comment: Of course because your article doesn't have an image field. You implement the uploader on the Painting class not on Article class. And you're trying to call it on on article object, that's why it's not working.

Comment: so wouldn't that mean I can copy and past "mound_uploader :image, ImageUploader" in my article.rb file? (https://github.com/BBaughn1/saving-git/blob/master/app/models/article.rb)

Comment: and, if you don't mind.. Can you post the code down below of how I should get the painting class to have a relationship with the Article? I never had to do this before and I'm relatively new to this *intense* kind of stuff on Ruby.. Thank you kindly

Comment: I edit my answer to show you how to set this. Good luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85366/discussion-between-coding-addicted-and-brendon-baughn).

Comment: you. are. awesome, thank you so much, it works :) if I could, I would check this green about 99 times. Have a good time coding, and thanks again :D

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you'll like your rails experience as I did when I started using it.